# WordPress customizer customize a page

Tags: wordpress

Can you customize any other page than the home page in the customizer? if yes, how?

The customizer api does not have any way to imput a url when creating a action for it. ex:

```
function mytheme_customize_register( $wp_customize ) {
   //All our sections, settings, and controls will be added here
}
add_action( 'customize_register', 'mytheme_customize_register' );
```

So, I'm asking, is there a way?

Comment: I think you're confusing things here, you customize ELEMENTS, so when inside customizer, you can navigate through pages and customize other pages if you want. If your question is how to load another page by default, that is a very different question, but bottom line is you can customize anything and everything from customizer. If what you need is to load another page, let me know and I'll add it as an answer

Answer (score 1):

When you provide a customizing option in the Customizer Pane, you can change the URL in the preview panal. For example: changing the previewed URL when the "Page for posts" changes, you can use the following code:

```js
// Change the previewed URL to the selected page when changing the page_for_posts.
wp.customize( 'page_for_posts', function( setting ) {
    setting.bind( function( pageId ) {
        pageId = parseInt( pageId, 10 );
        if ( pageId > 0 ) {
            api.previewer.previewUrl.set( api.settings.url.home + '?page_id=' + pageId );
        }
    });
});
```

Using the above same concept, you can change the preview URL.

Answer (score 0):

anyways, just in case you need it since I'm going out, here you go:

```
$admin_bar->add_menu( array(
        'id'    => 'my_page',
        'parent' => 'customize_page',
        'title' => 'My Page',
        'href' => admin_url( 'customize.php?url='. site_url('/my_page/') )
        'meta'  => array(
            'title' => __('My Page'),
            'target' => '_self',
            'class' => 'my_menu_item_class'
        ),
```

Comment: Hey Fabio. That's cool but, if you try that code and then go to the "Close" button (top left) in the customizer and click it, it goes to that page. I am trying to customize the wp-login.php page. And it goes to that page when I click it.I kind of was here already by doing this with add_menu_page. Same result. Any idea?

Comment: The problem is the customizer. And adding a page to it properly. I looked at the customizer. php code from the admin and got that a URL parameter changes the customizer path. But it also affects the closer button. And for my case, trying to customize the admin login page, is not a good choice.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to pass an `url` parameter, like so:

```
http://example.com/wp-admin/customize.php?url=PREVIEW_URL
```

One way is adding a menu item that links directly to a specific page:

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', function() 
{
    add_theme_page(
        'Custom customizer', 
        'Custom customizer', 
        'install_plugins', 
        'customize.php?url=' . urlencode('http://EXAMPLE.COM/hello-world/') 
    );
});
```